# ColdFusion 2016: can't install hotfix 5 on RedHat

Tags: coldfusion, hotfix, coldfusion-2016

I installed Cold Fusion 2016 on Red Hat 6.8 with apparent success.

I then tried to install "hotfix 5" with security and bug fixes, but it prompts me for an installation directory:

```
Select the home directory of your  installation. For example, 
/Applications/
For J2EE installation, it is the WAR directory containing WEB-INF, 
CFIDE and META-INF

Where is  located? (Default: /opt):
```

... but refuses to accept any answer I give, including the actual top directory **/opt/coldfusion2016**.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Did hot fixes up through 4 get in OK? Do any of this issue that are fixed apply to your apps? You may have to put a ticket in with Adobe and skip this update.

Comment: I thought hotfix 5 was inclusive of the previous ones but in any event this is the only one I got in the list of software I was supposed to install ...

Comment: What version of the Java JDK are you running ColdFusion on?  Update 5 requires a minimum version as part of the security fixes.  See http://blogs.coldfusion.com/coldfusion-2016-update-5-and-coldfusion-11-update-13-released/ for more details on that.

Comment: jdk 1.7.0_151 (openJDK on Linux) ... but this is from the customer who's apparently been running this software suite successfully ...

Comment: I believe ColdFusion 2016 is only certified on Java 8, so if they're running on Java 7 they may be in unsupported territory.  It may be the update installer isn't even compatible with Java 7.

Can you look at the Installed Updates tab in the Updates section of CF Administrator?  What updates are _already_ on that server?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to run it as:

```
java -jar hotfix.name.jar
```

from within the directory

```
/opt/coldfusion2016/cfusion/hf-updates
```

... and then it worked.

Also: I found the `findjava.sh` script that verifies the java version and java 7 is required, not java 8.